# Login Loop and wrong resolution AMD

Tags: login, amd-graphics

So, yesterday i used my ubuntu 16.04.3 fine, no problems whatsoever. Today i booted and suddenly i can't login, every time I put my password in it just blinked black and went back to the login screen, for every account I tried. I could login on tty1-6 so even tho I didn't update anything yesterday or changed any setting i looked at the Xauthoritys. They were fine, I reinstalled lightdm, didnt help. I then uninstalled my graphics driver (amdgpu-pro) and radeon, reinstalled radeon and succes, I can login again. But now my screen resolution is stuck to 4:3 instead of 16:9. I went into the settings but it now says it's a "built-in display" which is false, but I can't change the resolution.

I tried reinstalling the graphics driver again, hoping this would fix it but the resolution is still messed up and now I can't login again. Any help would be appreciated because I didn't change any settings and suddenly Ubuntu is misbehaving. I have an AMD R7 250 GPU and A10 processor. When I do the lspci command it does show my GPU and CPU and all drivers correctly loaded so I'm at a loss here. If you require any outputs from the system I'll post them.

EDIT: I temporarily got around the resolution by editing the grub file, but without the drivers I can no longer play my games. I have resorted to using my windows boot for now.

PS: Also my ethernet doesn't work anymore in the graphical interface, but in tty1-6 I do have internet. what's up with that?